# What should I do if there is no stress concentration for my shape?

Tags: stresses, solid-mechanics

Engineering textbooks have graphs like these for finding the stress concentrations for plates with holes, fillets and what not.

[image]

What should I do when I get a shape that does not have its stress concentrations listed in those graphs? Take for example this shape.

[image]

It is so simple yet I cannot find any stress concentrations for a shape like it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While Tomas Letal answer is probably the best way, I would like to add, that another option if you are trying to do some hand calculations and you are not infront of a workstation (very unusual in the trade nowadays), is to use a worst case scenario.

E.g. for the object that you have in the image, you could use the maximum of the stress concentration of a circle with diameter equal to  :

- the vertical width of the slot. Or,
- twice the radius of the corner

However, the best and easiest way is to use FEA, just make sure to check the mesh quality around the edges (usually you'd need to perform some sort of benchmarking with known cases).

Answer (score 3):

You could conduct simplified plate/beam analysis of a symmetrical quarter of your geometry and use stress concentration factor for L-shape with rounded corner. Or use FEA.

Comment: If the shape cannot be broken down into shapes which have pre-existing concentration charts, is my only option to use FEA or run physical experiments?

Comment: Generally yes, because analytical solutions can be reasonably done only for few basic shapes. But it may also depend on whether you actually need the stress value at the hot spot. For example, in pressure vessels design, you can use simple bending + axial stress calculation, and then check if the maximum is below two yield strengths, which should guarantee there will be no progressive plastic deformation after repeated loading. It is sort of partial cyclic loading assessment without the need for exact stress value at the hot spot.